# How to log RequestCharge for Cosmos DB CountAsync and MaxAsync operations when we don't get metrics for the respective functions?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

There doesn't seem to be a metric for CountAsync and MaxAsync operations of Cosmos DB. Does anyone know a better way to log Request Charge for these operations?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following code snippet for each of those operations:

```
System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("x-ms-request-charge"));
```

Please take a look at the [Query Documents - Responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents#response) for a list of headers available.